# How to update the fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm a beginner with php and fullcalendar.I need to update the calendar with the user input value ($('#name')). But it doesn´t work.

I have this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var UsrAux;
     $('#name').blur(function(){                    
        UsrAux = $('#name').val()      // <-- This is the input
      });                 


    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        draggable: true, 
        height: 400,    
        cache: true, 
        eventSources: [
    // your event source
        {
            url: 'CalendarServer.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {                     
                    uno: 'Something',   
                    UsrCdg: UsrAux                                          
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error!');
            },
            color: '#e2ebef',   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
        }
        ]       
      });


});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `blur` event function should be defined before the `fullCalendar` as it gets the data (the user input) you need.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I defined the blur before the fullcaledar. bu it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi finally. This is my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var UsrAux;     
        UsrAux=$('#name').val();                  
         $('#name').blur(function(){    
            UsrAux=$('#name').val();                        
            var source =   {
                    url: 'CalendarServer.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {                         // Parms
                            uno: 'Somenthing',  
                            UsrCdg: UsrAux                                          
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('error!');
                    },
                    color: '#e2ebef',   // a non-ajax option
                    textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
            };                               
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', source);
            });  



        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            draggable: true, 
            height: 400,    
            cache: true, 
            eventSources: [
        // your event source
            {
                url: 'CalendarServer.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {                         // Parms
                        uno: 'something',   
                        UsrCdg: $('#name').val()                                            
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('error!');
                },
                color: '#e2ebef',   // a non-ajax option
                textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
            }
            ]       
          });


          });
```